# Should you tape drywall with EasySand?

Tags: drywall, drywall-mud

I've heard mixed reviews about bucket mud (All Purpose, Plus3), so I thought I'd look at bags.

However, there is no bagged All Purpose at any big box near me, so I am left with EasySand 45/90. Since this is a setting compound, I'm not sure if it has the same retention properties of All Purpose for taping. The Plus3 page says it can also be used for all stages of finishing (tape, fill and top).

I'm fine using the bucket Plus3 for the finish coat, lightweight and easy to sand, but for taping and fill coats, should I use bucket All Purpose or mix up some EasySand 45/90?

Time isn't really an issue, but ideally if using the setting compound works just as good as All Purpose, can make my small project a 1-2 day job, rather than waiting 24 hours between coats.

Comment: As someone that in new to setting compounds I will give you some advice. “Do not try to use setting compounds as a rookie” I can usually find bad mud work when it is diy and just about 100% new diy using setting mud or “hot mud” . The tape actually makes as much difference as the paper.

Comment: @EdBeal So I should just use the bucket All Purpose? Thin it out a bit?

Comment: I do use all purpose mud slightly wet with paper but a bit dryer if using mesh it depends on the job and conditions for what I use. Keep the plastic the bucket is sealed with and after you use some put the plastic in contact with the mud, if boxed mud squeeze air out of bag.

Comment: You've heard mixed reviews about pre-mixed mud? That's what 99% of homes are built with. Problems usually trace to framing or foundation issues, not the mud.

Comment: Ed's right--hot mud isn't for the novice. You have to mix small batches or you get behind and suddenly your bucket is hard and your tools are a mess. Plus, it's not as smooth and takes more force to apply. I'd only use it for early pre-fill if you're truly in a hurry.

Comment: @isherwood Should I go with the buckets of Plus3 for all phases? Or pick up an All Purpose to do the bedding and then top with the Plus3?

Comment: Either are probably fine, but I know nothing about your job. Read the labels and make a call. They're both good.

Comment: hot mud is great for small jobs like patching holes because it sets rapidly. if the job is so large that you can't finish in a day there's less advantage to hot mud.